Lizmap plugin not recognizing user rights to see server info
I have qgis server with lizmap-web-client on a windows server (port 3000). In the past I managed to connect to my server using lizmap qgis plugin, but latest release 3.7.8 (I upgraded it manually) gives me error.
I can't figure out why this happens. See the image below.
Before I dive into plugin python code, maybe someone has idea how to test response from the server or what could be wrong with my setup.
Lizmap server apart from that works OK. Even version 3.6 that was installed before gives me the same error (and it works).
I checked if my user has rights: View detailed server information and I tried to connect it with different user having Publish rights. I even checked if Publish user has that flag set and it has. I suspect this is a: Right: lizmap.admin.server.information.view
Any idea how to correct that ?

